# Can't reach IP using Python httplib

Tags: python, python-2.7, httplib

I can't connect to anything on my network using the IP address of the host. I can open a browser and connect and I can ping the host just fine. Here is my code:

```
from httplib import HTTPConnection

addr = 192.168.14.203
conn = HTTPConnection(addr)
conn.request('HEAD', '/') 

res = conn.getresponse()

if res.status == 200:
    print "ok"
else:
    print "problem : the query returned %s because %s" % (res.status, res.reason)
```

The following error gets returned:

```
socket.error: [Errno 51] Network is unreachable
```

If I change the addr var to `google.com` I get a 200 response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure, that `addr` shouldn't be a string?

Comment: 192.168.14.203 is a [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses).  Are you sure such an address exists on your local network?

Comment: It exists on a network that I am connected to via VPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the address and your proxy settings.

For making HTTP requests I recommend the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. It's much more high-level and user friendly compared to `httplib` and it makes it easy to [set proxies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=proxy#proxies):

```
import requests

addr = "http://192.168.14.203"
response = requests.get(addr)

# if you need to set a proxy:
response = requests.get(addr, proxies={"http": "...proxy address..."})

# to avoid using any proxy if your system sets one by default
response = requests.get(addr, proxies={"http": None})
```